# perfect Lie algebra but not semisimple

Tags: lie-algebras

Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is [perfect](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Perfect_Lie_algebra) if and only if $\mathfrak{g}=[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$.

And we know semisimple Lie algebra must satisfy the $\mathfrak{g}=[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$ then it's perfect.

What is the example of perfect Lie algebra but not semisimple? And what's the sufficient and necessary condition for a perfect Lie algebra to be semisimple Lie algebra?

Comment: See [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60498/lie-algebra-semisimple), and also [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028737/which-vector-spaces-have-a-perfect-lie-algebra-structure).

Answer (score 5):

I think the set of $4$-by-$4$ matrices of the form
$$\pmatrix{*&*&*&*\\*&*&*&*\\0&0&*&*\\0&0&*&*}$$
will be an example.

Comment: you need to prescribe both diagonal blocks to have trace zero.

Answer (score 3):

Take any semisimple Lie algebra $L$ of dimension $n$ and an irreducible representation $V$ of $L$, of dimension $m \ge 2$ and define a bracket on $L \times V$ by
$$ [(X,v),(Y,u)] := ([X,Y],Xu-Yv). $$
This turns $L \times V$ into a perfect Lie algebra with $\text{Rad}(L \times V) = V$. The dimension is $n+m$. It is not semisimple.

A necessary and sufficient condition for a perfect Lie algebra to be semisimple is that its solvable radical is trivial.