# Lie algebra structure on $\mathbb{C}[G]$

Tags: finite-groups, lie-algebras, group-rings, semisimple-lie-algebras, dynkin-diagrams

Let $G$ be a finite group. The group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ has a Lie algebra structure inherited by its associative algebra structure, which is given by
$$[g,h]=gh-hg.$$
It is not too hard to check that the center $Z(\mathbb{C}[G])$ consists of the subspace of functions constant on conjugacy classes (upon identification of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ with the space of functions $G \to \mathbb{C}$). Moreover, $[\mathbb{C}[G],\mathbb{C}[G]]$ is the subspace of functions whose sum on every conjugacy class is zero. In particular we have $\mathbb{C}[G]=Z(\mathbb{C}[G])\oplus [\mathbb{C}[G],\mathbb{C}[G]]$, so it is reductive.

> **Question:** What can we say about the structure of the semi-simple part
> $[\mathbb{C}[G],\mathbb{C}[G]]$, in particular what is its
> corresponding Dynkin diagram?

Comment: See also [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60447/how-does-the-group-algebra-look-as-a-lie-algebra), where in the first case Lie algebra is a sum of general linear Lie algebras. Of course then the semisimple part is $\bigoplus_V \mathfrak{sl}(V)$. See also [this linked paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.0074.pdf).

Comment: Although it is true in hindsight as per Dietrich Burde's link (structure of semisimple associative algebras), I do not think you can conclude that the Lie algebra is reductive from just what you write.

Comment: Isn't it true that reductive is equivalent to $\mathfrak{g} = [\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]\oplus Z(\mathfrak{g})$?

Comment: I think both answers in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2424899/96384 show that is not the case (they have trivial centre and are perfect but not semisimple).